# Symfony2 response - Clear cache headers on back button

Tags: caching, symfony, response, symfony-2.1, cache-control

I have an issue with clearing my cache when back button is pressed.

My header information is saying i'ts loaded from cache:

```
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
```

My response is set to:

```
$response = new Response;
$response->expire();
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate', true);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('allow_reload', true);
```

What am I doing wrong? None of the documentation methods seem to work...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taking advice from [this article](http://blog.55minutes.com/2011/10/how-to-defeat-the-browser-back-button-cache/) and setting listed Cache-Control directives worked for me - by pressing back button request to the server was always sent.

```
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-cache', true);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('max-age', 0);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate', true);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-store', true);
```

Comment: GREAT! Thank you very much Gatisl! Worked like a charm!

Comment: This is a lifesaver. FWIW, it works great with Silex as well as it uses Symfony2's HTTP components.